# how to submit html forms onClick we out using submit button or enter

Tags: php, javascript

Can someone help me with a better way on submitting a form which has only hidden fields but it is required to enable MySQL to fetch data?
Like in my case I have names fetched from database and been displayed as title on a DIV which changes another DIV status using java from **Display none to block** when clicked, Therefore I wish to display the selected name results in a **Display Block DIV** which Contains an Iframe because I can not fetch all the information when the page is loading there is too much information it will cause the page to slow down, Then I decided to add some JavaScript to **Display None DIV** so when clicked it should set DIV Display Block and submit the ID of the selected person hidden form

```
document.$username.submit()
```

But the problem is only working in Firefox and Netscape Navigator other browsers are just showing the BLOCK DIV with nothing inside

Comment: People still use Netscape?

Comment: @Kolink that's where my jaw dropped as well.

Comment: that's not the ans, please

Comment: That's why we put it in comments, not in answers.

Comment: Netscape is DONE, FINISHED. The technology hasn't been supported since March 1, 2008, over 5 years ago. If you have having a problem with Netscape there is NO ONE HERE who can help you.

Comment: don't use iframes, use ajax instead

Comment: @Dagon how can I write that Ajax script, sorry I never write that Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a unique `id` to the form, like in `<form id="myform">`, then use simple JS to submit it:

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

The `document.elementName` syntax you use has been deprecated for like years now.

[Sample in JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/6L7kP/). If you open the network tab of your browser you can see it's succesfully submitting to http://www.stackoverflow.com/?foo=bar when you click the button.